# Trying to get Channel ID of Channel user joined Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get the Channel ID of the Channel that the new user joins. I'm using Discord.py and `discord.on_member_join()` however the only parameters it accepts is `Member` which doesn't hold the Channel ID, at least I don't believe it does. This is important because I have a bot auto assigning roles based on the channel the user joins (aka which invite link they use)

Comment: No, this isn't possible. Discord doesn't send that information to your bot. `Member` objects don't store information about any invites they may have used, `Invite` objects don't store information about the users that have used them, and the information isn't available as part of the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see doing this is have the bot keep track of all the invite in the server and then when a user joins check which invite uses has increased by one and get the channel of that invite.

You can use the `invites_from(server)` function to get a list of all the invites in the server. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.invites_from

Invites have the `.uses` property which will give you the number of times that invite has been used and you can use the `.channel` property to get the channel the invite is for.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Invite%20%22discord.Invite